Unable to post photos into facebook page using GraphAPI error #200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available. It has been deprecated
Following facebook's GraphAPI docs, i got a post request as seen below:
https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/{pageid}/photos?access_token={here I insert a permanent PAGE token}&url={here i insert a url of a image that does exist}

The response of this post request is:
 "error": {
    "message": "(#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available. It has been deprecated. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "Asd0O0G-dN02eCY9jLJjQGG"
  }
}

Using the answers from others having the same error, I tried using permanent and short-term USER/PAGE access tokens. All resulted in the exact same error
